# I lost my projects when I upgraded netbeans 7.0 to netbeans 7.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans, project

Yesterday I updated NetBeans from 7.0 to 7.0.1 and it made me lose all my projects. They're still physically there on my hard drive, but NetBeans does not recognise them as Projects.

The anoying thing about this mostly is that they are all PHP projects that use a remote FTP connection, So simply putting them back in is not an option, I'll have to add a new project, setup the FTP connection and to complete the wizard NetBeans needs to download all the external resources that takes up about 1.5 hours for each project...

Luckily I still found an installed NetBeans 7 Beta 2 somewhere that still had the projects in it. So I'll be using that one for now, but I'd really like to see my old projects working again on the last version of NetBeans.

Can anyone help me with putting my old projects into my new NetBeans 7.0.1?

Answer (score 5):

you can use the import option in netbeans to recover them. just point the new net beans to the projects you want recovered.

Comment: see its not a new project. so thats not where u would look. but in the same menu you will find import option. please look at the application UI a bit more carefully

Comment: see there also an option of open project. use that. am sure that will do the trick

Comment: Nothing works.. I just deleted .netbeans folder and now its working but downgrade to 7.0